# How to add JPanel to a JFrame

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

I am a beginner in java and I have this objective to be done: [image]

This is my partial code:

public class Trial extends JFrame {

```
public static final int WIDTH = 800;
public static final int HEIGHT = 600;
public static final int SCALE = 3;

private BufferedImage backBuffer;

public KeyboardInput input;
private Stage stage;
public static Trial Trial;
public static String message = "";
private Object Object;
private Message MessageBox;

public void init() {
    this.Trial = this;
    input = new KeyboardInput();
    this.addWindowListener(new WinListener());
    this.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    this.setResizable(false);
    this.setUndecorated(false);
    this.setVisible(true);
    this.addKeyListener(input);
    client = new TrialClient(SERVER_IP, this);
    MessageBox = new Message(username);
    backBuffer = new BufferedImage(WIDTH * SCALE, HEIGHT * SCALE, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
}

public Stage getStage() {
    return stage;
}

public class WinListener extends WindowAdapter {

    @Override
    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
        disconnect();
        System.exit(0);
    }

}


private Font font = new Font("Munro Small", Font.PLAIN, 96);
private Font font2 = new Font("Munro Small", Font.PLAIN, 50);
private Font fontError = new Font("Munro Small", Font.PLAIN, 25);
private int op = 0;


public void updateMenu() {
    if (input.up.isPressed()) {
        input.up.toggle(false);
    } else if (input.down.isPressed()) {
        input.down.toggle(false);
    } else if (input.enter.isPressed() && op == 0) {
    } else if (input.enter.isPressed() && op == 1) {
        System.exit(0);
    }
}


public void drawMenu() {
    Graphics g = getGraphics();
    Graphics bbg = backBuffer.getGraphics();
    bbg.setFont(font);
    bbg.setColor(Color.white);

    bbg.drawString("Sample", 189, 180);
    bbg.setFont(font2);
    if (op == 0) {
        bbg.setColor(Color.red);
        bbg.drawString("Start", 327, 378);
    }

    g.drawImage(backBuffer, 0, 0, this);
}

public void draw() {
    Graphics g = getGraphics();
    Graphics bbg = backBuffer.getGraphics();
    bbg.setColor(Color.black);
    bbg.fillRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    stage.drawStage(bbg, this);
    for (Object t : stage.getPlayers()) {
        t.draw(bbg, SCALE, this);
    }
    g.drawImage(backBuffer, 0, 0, this);
}


public void drawLogin() {
    Graphics g = getGraphics();
    Graphics bbg = backBuffer.getGraphics();
    bbg.setColor(Color.black);
    bbg.fillRect(0, 0, 800, 600);
    bbg.setColor(Color.red);
    bbg.setFont(fontError);
    bbg.drawString(message, 100, 100);
    bbg.setFont(font2);
    bbg.setColor(Color.white);
    bbg.drawString("Username", 284, 254);
    bbg.setColor(Color.red);
    bbg.drawString(username, 284, 304);
    g.drawImage(backBuffer, 0, 0, this);
}



public class StringWait extends Thread {

    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            }
        }
    }
}

public void start() {
    init();
    while (true) {
       ...
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Trial g = new Trial();
    g.start();
}
```

}

how will I declare the Jpanel in JFrame? Or there is a way to create a Jpanel in different window after the JFrame was created? I am doing this in netbeans.

Comment: don't add them in the init method, define the variables as netbeans normally do outside of a method in the class body

Comment: use Netbeans's Java Swing GUI builder?

Comment: How will I do that?sorry I'm beginner in java

Comment: the variable section looks like generated by netbeans, so just leave it as you created the components in the netbeans gui editor. if not created by netbeans, google "netbeans swing editor", you'll get enough results

Comment: How will I declare my function that contains the JPanel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare variable outside init methode
Create jpanel, add component to the panel
create jscrollpane with panel as view
set jscrollpane as contentpane of your frame
see exemple below

```
public class Game extends JFrame {

public Game() throws HeadlessException {
    setSize(100, 100);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setResizable(false);
    setVisible(true);
}

private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
private javax.swing.JTextArea jTextArea1;
private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;

void init() {

    jButton1 = new JButton("jButton1");

    jTextArea1 = new JTextArea("jTextArea1");
    jTextField1 = new JTextField("jTextField1");
    JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
    panel2.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    panel2.add(jTextField1);
    panel2.add(jButton1);
    jPanel1 = new JPanel();
    jPanel1.setLayout(new BoxLayout(jPanel1, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    jPanel1.add(jTextArea1);
    jPanel1.add(panel2);
    jScrollPane1 = new JScrollPane(jPanel1);
    setContentPane(jScrollPane1);
    System.out.println("init");
    revalidate();
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    Game g = new Game();
    //wait just to find the effect of revalidate
    Thread.sleep(1000);

    g.init();
}
```

}

Comment: Is it possible to create a separate JPanel in another window?

Comment: what you mean by another window?

Comment: nevermind the two window. I am having trouble in trying to show the Jpanel. It seems that the code you've given to me is correct but the JFrame overlaps the JPanel. How will I make it visible?

Comment: i have modified the code. You must call the method revalidate() of JFrame to make the new contentpane visible
See the code, it is updated

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is that the line

```
backBuffer = new BufferedImage(WIDTH * SCALE, HEIGHT * SCALE, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
```

please modify it, so that it will not occupy the whole area.

Answer (score 1):

Just declare a variable JPanel and add it to the Frame.

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
this.setContentPane(panel);
```

Comment: It's not that easy, your panel will not contain any components and will not have the padding at the top

Comment: He is just asking about the JPanel

Comment: In the comments he is asking to add all of the components.

Comment: How will I declare the function that contains the JPanel?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add

`JPanel panel = new JPanel();`

and other declarations inside the init(), then make sure that BufferedImage function don't overlaps on it